# Is there a way to enforce InteliJ code style formatting before committing to Git?

Tags: java, git, intellij-idea, ide, githooks

We would like to create a common code style for all the team in order to solve the problem of different formats which make files look "dirty" during code review although they don't contain actual meaningful change

The steps:

1. Create InteliJ code style XML
2. Import this XML into all our IDE (InteliJ)
3. Go to each git repository ( ~30) and create a commit which will reformat all the code.

My question is, is there a way to enforce that from now on all the commits will be aligned to this new format ?

for example a developer which will try to commit a code which is not formatted will get an error message and it's push will get aborted.

Comment: Are you using Maven or something? If so, you could force one of the existing plugins  . Before `git commit` would need to somehow overwrite the command. in Linux that would be a simple alias

Comment: Yes, most are repositories are Mavan based, can you please explain how we can use Maven in order to enforce the formatting ?

Comment: The easiest thing is to enable "Before Commit | Reformat Code" in IntelliJ IDEA. This will not abort commits, but I think that's a good thing (imagine needing to fix a really urgent problem and fighting with a bot which doesn't let you commit your fix because of a missing space character)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are commiting code using IntelliJ you can configure some "Before Commit" rules on the IDE.

On Windows go to File -> Settings -> Version Control -> Commit Dialog.
You will see 3 checkboxes: "Reformat Code", "Rearrange code", "Optimize Imports".

On Mac -> Preferences ->Version Control -> Commit Dialog.

Of course, this will only apply your style if you commit through the IDE.

If you want a plain GIT solution, you should take a look at git hooks. Hooks are little pieces of code (you could call them plug-ins) that allow you to extend git functionality. You can also version them as part of the project.

This is a very detailed explanation of how to address the same issue you are having: https://proandroiddev.com/ooga-chaka-git-hooks-to-enforce-code-quality-11ce8d0d23cb

Git hooks can also be applied to more complex code management Solutions based on Git, (i.e.: bitbucket).

Comment: Thanks Diego and yole, this covers 90% of our team which use Intelij version control functionality, but for the rest of the 10% who use external tools or the command line this will not work, do you have more information about this git hook approach ?

Comment: Sure, I updated my answer with some more detail. If you are using an enterprise Solution like bitbucket, gitlab, github, etc., i would probably apply the hook there so that you don't need to worry about every person in the team installing stuff. That would be a more robust approach.

Comment: Here is a link to Bitbucket documentation on how to apply a global hook at server-side. I'd guess that github and gitlab have the same feature:
https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/using-repository-hooks-776639836.html